Flexible margins using gridbox
Consider the following HTML and CSS:


.portion {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-template-areas: "pleft pcore pright";
}
<div class="portion">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="core"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>



I can't seem to figure out how to make the left and right classes behave. I want them adjust automatically as view width changes. min-width: 20px and max-width: 200px for left and right classes while the core adjusts between min-width: 320px and whatever space that is remaining.
How do I go about this?

Use the minmax value in your grid-template-columns.


.portion {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(20px, 200px) minmax(320px, 1fr) minmax(20px, 200px);
  grid-template-rows: auto;
}

.portion * {
  height: 100px;
  outline: 1px solid grey;
}
<div class="portion">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="core"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>




This works.  However,. when I replace the literals with var() the result changes. It appears minmax() does not play well with var().

Why not? I please post the code you are using with var(). And the code where you defined the variable for var.

@DavidWeber I stand corrected. I have checked again and I was wrong
